# how to customize the table name for the AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm implementing Identity and wants to customize the table names. I have successfully customized all tables except "AspNetUsers".

Code:

```
builder.Entity<UserProfile>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityUserProfile"));
builder.Entity<User>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityUser"));
builder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityRole"));
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityUserRole"));
builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityUserClaim"));
builder.Entity<UserProfileLogin>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityUserProfileLogin"));
builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityUserToken"));
builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>(opt => opt.ToTable("IdentityRoleClaim"));
```

the type *UserProfile* inherits *IdentityUser*, so I would like to rename AspNetUsers to IdentityUserProfile

any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so similarly to how you already tried, like so:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
{
    b.ToTable("IdentityUserProfile");
});
```

This will rename the table implemented by the base type `IdentityUser`